# get watij to run

Tags: java, watij

i downloaded watij and am trying to get it to run in eclipse. i tried this sample code

WebSpec spec = new WebSpec().safari();
spec.safari().open("http://www.google.com");

and WebSpec is underlined in red saying WebSpec cannot be resolved into a type
I assume this means that something has not been added into my project.
I right clicked on my src folder and added the .jar files and then added webspec.jar to the project also

Are there any steps that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't put JAR files in your src folder.  They are not source files.

Create a lib folder, put the JAR files there, and then add them to the project's build path.

Comment: so if my project name is eclipse..do i right click on that and add the lib folder there with all the jar files? and then where does the webspec.jar file get added?

Comment: @Aaron - yes.  In fact, the folder could be called anything you like ... but "lib" is conventional.  *"And then where does the webspec.jar file get added?"*  - In the directory you just created ... of course.

Comment: ok so i did that and then added the folder to the build path but WebSpec is still recording a syntax error.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Is there an "import" statement in the class containing that code?  (Basic Java 101 stuff ... though the getting started example on the watij.com site doesn't bother to mention it.)